# How to display the ID of outliers on a boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I want to display the IDs that have extreme values on a boxplot but I have no idea how to do it.
For example the IDs corresponding to the values 10, 98 and 120

```
Poids<-c(round(rnorm(100,65,10),1),10,53,120,98)

ID<-c(paste("A",1:26,sep = ""),paste("B",1:26,sep = ""),paste("C",1:26,sep = ""),
paste("D",1:26,sep = ""))

mydata<-data.frame(ID=ID,Poids=Poids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` packages you can create a subset inside `geom_text`, here how:

#### Data

```
Poids <- c(round(rnorm(100,65,10),1),10,53,120,98)

ID <- c(paste("A",1:26,sep = ""),paste("B",1:26,sep = ""),paste("C",1:26,sep = ""),
      paste("D",1:26,sep = ""))

mydata <- data.frame(ID=ID,Poids=Poids)
```

### Setting values manually

#### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Poids))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_text(
    data = mydata %>% filter(Poids %in% c(10,98,120)),
    mapping = aes(y = 0,label = ID),
    nudge_y = .05
  )
```

#### Output

[image]

### Using boxplot outlier criteria

#### Code

```
# remotes::install_github("vbfelix/relper")
library(relper)

mydata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Poids))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_text(
    data = mydata %>% filter(is_outlier(Poids)),
    mapping = aes(y = 0,label = ID),
    nudge_y = .05
  )
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there a way to let the function to detect and displays automately the outliers without manually define the values?

Comment: Sure, you just need to define a outlier criteria first

Comment: Thanks I found some tools to spot outliers